# Spark Web UI showing Job SUCCEEDED but Tasks Succeeded Less than Total

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

In the "Details for Job *n* section, the UI shows "Status: SUCCEEDED", however one of the Stages shows 22029 succeeded Tasks out of 59400 total tasks. I'm running this through a Python Jupyter notebook running Spark 3.0.1, and I haven't stopped the Spark context yet so the application is still running. In fact, the Stages Tab shows the stage in question as still active. I don't understand how the stage could still be active, yet the Job is listed as Completed and Successful in the UI.

The relevant code (I think) is below, where I try to parallelize as much as possible many SQL queries and then union the result dataframes together. Lastly, I'm writing them to cloud storage in parquet.

[image: Spark Jobs UI view]

EDIT: I also can see the same information from the REST API using the endpoints documented [here in the docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/monitoring.html#rest-api), and those values are the same as I see in the Web UI.

There are no jobs appearing in the Jobs tab as failed, and I believe that ultimately the data is successfully written and correct.

I have seen in the logs many instances of `Dropping event from queue appStatus. This likely means one of the listeners is too slow and cannot keep up with the rate at which tasks are being started by the scheduler.` Because of that, I am experimenting with the parameter `spark.scheduler.listenerbus.eventqueue.capacity` to increase it and see if that results in a difference in the reporting of Succeeded and Total tasks for that stage.

Upon increasing `spark.scheduler.listenerbus.eventqueue.capacity` from default of 10000 to 65000, there seems to be a corresponding decrease in events dropped, as well as an increase in Succeeded Tasks reported for that stage, improving to ~ 47K from ~ 22K. I have also noticed that the difference in Succeeded and Total tasks for that stage is on the order of the number of dropped events in the log so I will see if limiting the dropped events can resolve the discrepancy.

```
def make_df(query: str):
    df = spark.sql(query)
    return df

spark.conf.set("spark.sql.sources.partitionOverwriteMode", "dynamic")

df_list = list(map(make_df, queries))

df = functools.reduce(lambda x, y: x.union(y), df_list)

df.repartition("col1", "col2")\
    .write.partitionBy("col1", "col2")\
    .mode("overwrite")\
    .parquet(path)
```

Why would my job be reporting as Successful when there are still tasks remaining that aren't successful?

Comment: could you show the failed jobs tab as well?

Comment: did your job actually fail? was the data not written?

Comment: @mck Failed Jobs tab is not visible, and my understanding is that means that all of the jobs are considered Success from the [docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.1/web-ui.html#jobs-tab) . Will update the question with this info, thanks.

Comment: @Andy_101 I _believe_ the job was actually successful. Data was written and appears to be the same as my previous code that ran on a single node and earlier Spark version. I'm testing more to confirm or disprove this. Also tweaking the `spark.scheduler.listenerbus.eventqueue.capacity` parameter since I saw many "Dropping event from queue appStatus" log messages. Will update this in the question, thanks for your response.